# How to access remote desktop from two machines in windows azure

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, azure-web-roles

I published the cloud service from VS2010 with Remote Desktop enabled. I downloaded the remote desktop connection for that instance. I just logged in to cloud server using Remote Desktop. Now i published same application from another computer. When i want to connect Remote Desktop from new machine its unable to connect to server. Even i tried from previous machine i am getting the same thing.

Application has 1 role & 1 instance. help me with this thing.

Comment: Is it possible the remote desktop configuration is different? It's supposed to be store in the app's service definitions, is it possible that one machine had a different configuration than the other?

Answer (score 0):

You must allow the RDP while publishing it to the cloud...Check the publish settings once...